# I try to render something in PHP and doesn't work

Tags: php, onclick

I need help with the following code:

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component{ //este es el elemento de la sidebare, aca voy a poner todo lo que quiera 

    constructor (props){ // constructor de ciertos parametros
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            logo :"logo-head-dark", //este es el logo (ver porque esta roto cuando pongo __riple.theme  + )
            nav: [
    {
        
    }
    
            ] //fin del nav
        }  //fin del state
    } //fin del constructor
    
    
    render (){ // renderiza lo que voy a mostrar  
        // sudebar fixed es la barra lateral
    return (
    <div className = "sidebar fixed"> 
    <a href={__riple.base} className="abs logo"><img src={__riple.theme +  "ui/" + this.state.logo} className="bl" /></a>
    <ul className="nav">
        {
    this.props.datanav.map((item,index ) =>{
        var on = this .state.page == item.link || (this.state.page === "index" && item.link === "")?  "on" : "";
        
        return <li key = {"nav-" + index}> 
        
             <a href={ __riple.base + item.link } data-page={item.link} data-title={item.label} data-link={item.link} 
             className={"bl noul anim " + on}>
 onClick = {(e)=>{
                     riple.stop(e);
                     loadPage(e.currentTarget.dataset.page);
                     console.log(e.target.dataset);
                     console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset);


                 }}

                <div className={"ibl ico " + item.icon} > {item.icon}</div>
                
    <span className="lbl" >{item.label}</span>
             </a>
        </li>
    })
    
    }
    </ul>
    </div>
    )
    }
    }
    //chequear porque la imagen se ve rota
    ReactDOM.render(<Sidebar datanav={__riple.nav} />, document.getElementById("sidebar"));
    
const loadPage = (page) =>{
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById(riple.root));
switch(page) {
    case "index":
        console.log("Cargando  La pagina de index");
        ReactDOM.render(<AccountView mod ="signin"/>, document.getElementById(riple.root));
        break;
    case "account":

        break;
}
}

    riple.init();

    if (__riple.request.is === "page"){
var _= __riple.request.page;
loadPage(_);

    }
```

When I run my site it show the following error:
react-dom.development.js:82 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
In a (created by Sidebar)
in li (created by Sidebar)
in ul (created by Sidebar)
in div (created by Sidebar)
in Sidebar

Any idea on what is happening?

Comment: Simplify your code. Return less and less until that error stops appearing, then you’ve found your bug.

Answer (score 0):

To start (this may or may not resolve the issue) your `onClick` seems to be outside your `<a>` tag.

I would also reformat your code to make it a bit more readable.

```
<a 
   href={ __riple.base + item.link } 
   data-page={item.link} 
   data-title={item.label} 
   data-link={item.link} 
   className={"bl noul anim " + on}>
   onClick = {(e)=>{
                 riple.stop(e);
                 loadPage(e.currentTarget.dataset.page);
                 console.log(e.target.dataset);
                 console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset);
              }}
>
    <div className={"ibl ico " + item.icon} > {item.icon}</div>           
    <span className="lbl" >{item.label}</span>
</a>
```

Can go a long way in helping you find a bug like the `onClick` not being enclosed properly as a prop as well.

Comment: Thnak you so much!
I try what you said and work, now that doesnt throw me an error any more!
Sadly I cannot give you an upvote cause :Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @santiagorico If it worked you can mark this as the answer